# Seeking detailed description of qgs file structure?

Tags: qgis, qgs

Is there a detailed description on the `.qgs` file structure somewhere?

I checked at http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd and got

> The requested URL /qgis.dtd was not found on this server.

and at https://svn.osgeo.org/qgis/trunk/qgis/qgis.dtd which wasn't very detailed.

Comment: Very good question, and surprised we can't find a writeup on the XML that makes up the .qgs file. It's fairly straightforward to figure out some sections and [parse the file](http://press.underdiverwaterman.com/summarising-qgis-project-layers/) but full documentation should be somewhere!

Comment: This good question got me a "tumbleweed" badge :D

Comment: Didn't even know such a thing existed! Not as bad as the 'unsung hero' badge but ouch ... can't believe no one has piped up with an answer yet.

Comment: Here is the current file version: https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/qgis.dtd

Comment: @markusN That is pretty much the same file as the one in https://svn.osgeo.org/qgis/trunk/qgis/qgis.dtd

Answer (score 8):

It would seem there isn't. According to [bug report #4408](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/14340):

> It's not possible to validate a QGIS project or style file against the
> called *.dtd (http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd). Two reasons: the URL doesn't
> exist and using a *.dtd from SVN always returns a "non valid". Having
> the possibility to validate could decrease erroneous project files. As
> such it's a feature wish, but as long as QGIS mentions a *.dtd not
> working, it's a bug.

It was filed eleven months ago and last updated eight days ago. The target version for fixing the bug's version 2.0.0, too. If there is any detailed documentation then they'd have fixed it earlier, I think.