# Understanding QGIS project files

Tags: qgis, workspace, qgs

I'm a GIS software developer, I've been working predominantly with MapInfo over the last year or so but have now been tasked with assessing QGIS to see if we can perform the same tasks we've developed in MapInfo with QGIS. Or rather compare the performance of the 2. So I'm in the early stages of getting to know how QGIS works, and since I'm used to workspaces in MapInfo I'm trying to understand more about QGIS project files (.qgs).

I've had a scout around but I haven't been able to find any official .qgs documentation, or anything particularly useful elsewhere...does anyone know if this exists?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @AlexEastwood! I think a similar question was asked a few years ago without much success: [Is there a detailed description on the .qgs file structure somewhere?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32340/is-there-a-detailed-description-on-the-qgs-file-structure-somewhere)

Comment: @Joseph Thanks for the welcome! And yes I'd found that post yesterday and wanted to reference it here as well but I couldn't find the link any more. As you say, not much success there and the link provided isn't all too useful either. If I find any info I'll spread the word! Thanks

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question. As mentioned in the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), GIS SE is a database of focused questions and best answers. Multipart questions break that model, so the policy is to focus on the more pressing issue, then ask the other question(s) later.

Comment: @Vince OK I've read the tour, edited,and posted the 2nd question separately

Comment: I probably should have recommended that you pursue the second question here, since the first one was already asked (unanswered, but that is an answer in of itself)