# QGIS (qgs file) meaning of annotationform and editform tag

Tags: qgis, qgs

**What is the meaning of tags *annotationform* and *editform* in the qgs file?** The reason I ask is because there is only file path within. Mostly relative path as dot, sometimes path to something like ../../../My_Project/GIS. And by something I mean I have no idea why this path. Is it supposed to set path for some kind of form or whatever might be saved there or why? There is definitely not saved anything apart of qgs projects in that directory.

If I remove the paths from within these tags completely or leave simple dot is it ok? **What exactly is it going to affect**?

Comment: Maybe even better I would be really glad if there is some document explaining QGS file structure / tags in general. But I am afraid http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32340/seeking-detailed-description-of-qgs-file-structure/167705  says there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple questions, and I think answering one will help you be informed to solve your issues...

To explain about the dot dot (..), this means to refer to the parent directory in the path.  In your case of:

> (../../../My_Project/GIS)

This "relative path" is telling the program to go back 3 folders from it's current working folder then go into the 'My_Project' folder then the 'GIS' folder.

If you are having path issues then a relative path could be an issue if you have moved some of your project files around.

You can replace the ../ with an absolute path but that could cause issues as well if you intend to move your project elsewhere after development.

You can see how relative paths are useful when moving from a development environment path (c:\testing\project\6.0\My_Project\GIS) to a live one (c:\program files\project\6.0\My_Project\GIS).

This link explains more about the dot dot (..):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066435/what-do-the-dots-mean-in-relative-file-path

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry it might not be clear but I am not asking about the paths at all, I am pretty familiar with both relative and absolute paths. My question is **What is the meaning of annotationform and editform in the qgs file** ? I am going te edit my question to make it hopefully more clear.

Comment: I'd like someone to answer his question regading annotationform and editform. I've resourced all my layers in my QGIS project to a new directory on a new Drive. However, in the QGIS project .qgs file, I'm seeing references to the old directories after **annotationform** and **editform**...