# Clean up QGIS project file *.qgs

Tags: qgis, qgs, template

I'm using a QGIS project as template for other projects. This template has got around 5000 rows. Because I do several updates to the file, it's getting larger and more complex by the time. I know, that some plugins leave there codes in the file, even if they are not installed to QGIS anymore. I would like to get rid of that residual codes because they slow down the project load time and could cause errors.

Is there a way to automatically clean up the QGIS-project-file? I'm looking for something similar to the ["SVG-Cleaner"](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/SVGCleaner) whit which you can clean up the XML-Code of a SVG.

Until now I was randomly recreating the project by copy and pasting the "good" stiles and codes from one QGIS window with the old project to another window with the new project.

Comment: I feel your pain. If there is an answer to this question I would be stoked!  
Also, you say "I know, that some plugins leave there codes in the file, even if they are not installed to QGIS anymore." ... is there a way of finding out which ones/what other settings etc./any remedies? P.S. do you know this plugin: "Copy layers and groups to clipboard"? ... works a treat for the layer and style copy and paste game!

Comment: Unless you can specify precisely what bits you want removed from the XML file that is a .qgs project, I don't see how we can answer this. Can you give us some XML examples and show us what needs removing? Otherwise this question is somewhat vague.

Comment: The point is, that I don't know, what or where is residual or 'orphaned' code. But I know, that it exist. I'm looking for a "cleaner" or a method to clean it up like you can do for SVG-xml with the SVG-cleaner: https://github.com/RazrFalcon/SVGCleaner

Comment: Perhaps you could mention which plugins you used which stored some code into your project?

Comment: @Joseph: the "Layer Combinations"-plugin for instance. It is deprecated since QGIS got the "Manage Layer Visibility"-Function.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such tool as far as I know. Since there is no schema for project files ([Seeking detailed description of qgs file structure?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32340/seeking-detailed-description-of-qgs-file-structure)), it would seem rather unsafe to run automatic cleaning.