# Restoring or repairing non-working QGIS file (*.qgs)?

Tags: qgis

It is the second time in a week that have lost the information in the project file (.qgs). When I load the project the only informationI see is the groups in the layers panel, but no layers.

I have no idea what went wrong, inspecting the .qgs file I see that all my layers, coniguration layers, data sources and a lot more are there (20k lines !!). My guess is that something could have gone wrong with some virtual layers, so I think I could get ride of them, but how?

I wonder if there is a way to retrieve some data and info in order to setup the project again from the .qgs file to build a project brick by brick and not start from zero.

System information: Windows 7 Enterprise, QGIS version 2.18.14

**Edited:**

I tried to use the .qgs~, but the problem persisted

Comment: I had the same problem for two times: "...the only information I see is the groups in the layers panel, but no layers"!. As you said, I think there could be an issue with Virtual Layers. I didn't know about the "~" file so I had to update an old backup file and had to insert a lot of missing layers. I'm using QGIS 2.18.10 Windows 7 64bit. Is there a bug?

Comment: did you name your memory layers in a certain manner? or are they all just called "temporary layer"

Comment: All of them have a specific name and it is human readable

Comment: I managed to copy and paste some blocks from the .qgs file to get the key layers back, but is far from optimal. I also learned there the way to the specifications is hard https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32340/seeking-detailed-description-of-qgs-file-structure

Comment: on windows 7 there is an option to restore previous versions of files https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/17119/windows-7-recover-lost-deleted-files

Comment: Do your file paths have spaces in them? Some features in QGIS are pickier than others about spaces in the file paths.

Answer (score 3):

When saving a QGIS project and altering a layer (removing or adding one) will create an additional file with the same name but a "~" at the end (see image). By removing the "~"  you can restore a project to its original state when it was last altered.

[image: example of QGIS project file].

I've tested this approach with a memory layer which resulted in the layer being present but the geometries were lost (Layer was empty) while other Layers (PostGIS) had all the geometries.

Comment: As updated in the question, I tried it without success. It was the first thing I did taking care of keeping the broken file as in their original states